# How do you prevent an Excel / ActiveX Command Button from being moved/edited, but allow it to be clicked

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I've got an ActiveX Command Button on a WorkSheet. I will be protecting the worksheet and need the button so it cannot be moved or changed, but still want it to be clickable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you protect the sheet, the button will not move and it will be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and protect the sheet. If macros are enabled the button should remain click-able.

Comment: One point is that I believe the DEVELOPER / DESIGN MODE needs to be off.